# C# - Convert unsafe byte* to byte[]

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have an `unsafe` `byte*` pointing to a native byte array of known length. How can I convert it to `byte[]`?

An `unsafe` `sbyte*` pointing to a zero-terminated native string can be converted to a C# `string` easily, because there is a [conversion constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975.aspx) for this purpose, but I can't find a simple way to convert `byte*` to `byte[]`.

Comment: shouldn'y `byte[]` be `const byte*` by default? so try indexing the pointer as `*(myByte+index);` But i guess it if were that easy you wouldn't be asking....

Comment: You should be able to write `*(myByte+index)` as `myByte[index]`. No conversion necessary.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I must convert it to byte[] because I have to pass it to the constructor of IPAddress.

Comment: But do you need safe (managed) `byte[]` or not?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The IPAddress ctor needs a safe/managed byte[]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `ptr` is your unsafe pointer, and the array has length `len`, you can use `Marshal.Copy` like this:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[len];
Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr, arr, 0, len);
```

But I do wonder how you came by an unsafe pointer to native memory. Do you really need unsafe here, or can you solve the problem by using `IntPtr` instead of an unsafe pointer? And if so then there's probably no need for unsafe code at all.

Comment: This looks good, I was gonna suggest traversing the pointed-to array and filling by hand, or memcpy, but this seems like a C# way of doing it. (y)

Comment: This question is a follow-up to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549123/c-sharp-performance-using-unsafe-pointers-instead-of-intptr-and-marshal

Comment: I'd err towards `IntPtr` and `Marshal.Copy` if I were you.

Comment: Thank you, David, I didn't know that an unsafe pointer can be casted to IntPtr.

Comment: "I'd err towards IntPtr and Marshal.Copy if I were you." - Why? I would also like to know your opinion on my other question (pls. check out the link if you have time). I haven't got any answers to that one, just some comments.

Comment: Well, in the scenario in this question, where you need a managed byte[], then there's really no need for unsafe. At the other question, you can use unsafe to avoid taking a copy of the native memory. If there's a performance gain by avoiding that copy that is significant, then unsafe becomes an option. Otherwise I'd always prefer not to use unsafe code.

Comment: Can I do the above without new (which may be lot of memory consuming) - just reference to the same memory?

Comment: @Eitan yes, using `Span<T>`

Comment: How can I do this without marshal.copy? I used unsafe code to get the byte array without using marshal copy to begin with, for performance reasons. Now I need to use marshalcopy anyways??

Comment: @savram ask a new question, because this questions asks something different from what you ask

Answer (score 1):

The [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal_methods.aspx) class could help you.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  bytes[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(yourPtr, i);
```

I think you might use Marshal.Copy too.

Comment: Since this has to happen in an unsafe block, you don't need `Marshal.ReadByte` and you can just use good old fashioned pointer de-reference and pointer increment. That is if you wish to perform the copy in a loop rather than using `Marshal.Copy`.