# Read-only array field in unsafe struct

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, getter, unsafe

This is the original declaration:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16)]
public unsafe struct X
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort a;
  [FieldOffset(2)] public fixed byte b[14];
};
```

I would like to make the `struct` read-only, but I don't know how I should write a getter for the array. The only solution I could figure out is a getter *method*:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16)]
public unsafe struct X
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] private ushort a;
  [FieldOffset(2)] private fixed byte b[14];

  public ushort A { get { return a; } }
  public byte B(int i) { fixed (byte* p = b) { return p[i]; } }
};
```

Is it possible to write a getter *property* for b instead of a getter *method*?

**=== UPDATE ===**

I would also like to handle the case when there are more than one array fields. For example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 24)]
public unsafe struct Y
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] private ushort a;
  [FieldOffset(2)] private fixed byte b[14];
  [FieldOffset(16)] private fixed byte c[8];

  public ushort A { get { return a; } }
  public byte B(int i) { fixed (byte* p = b) { return p[i]; } }
  public byte C(int i) { fixed (byte* p = c) { return p[i]; } }
};
```

Is it possible to write a getter *properties* for b and c instead of getter *methods*? I would like to write `y.B[i]` and `y.C[i]` instead of `y.B(i)` and `y.C(i)`.

Comment: You should only ever use a declaration like this for unmanaged code interop.  At that point, having a structure member read-only just doesn't mean anything anymore.  The language you interop with needs to declare it that way, maybe with *const*.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I need this for interop code. I have a byte* from 3rd party unmanaged lib and after adding an offset I cast it to pointers to similar unsafe structures. I just want (1) to stop the users of my code overwriting the original unmanaged data, and (2) to modify some fields inside the getter. So I made every field private and added getters.

Comment: Never expose unsafe structures to client code.  It is unsafe and nobody likes having to turn on the option.

Comment: @HansPassant I needed to do this to achieve the prescribed performance. Actually this question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549123/c-sharp-performance-using-unsafe-pointers-instead-of-intptr-and-marshal

Answer (score 3):

You can use an indexer propertie to access the array at a particular index. Unfortunately it needs to be defined on the struct itself rather than B, but this should provide what you're looking for:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16)]
public unsafe struct X
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private ushort a;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    private fixed byte b[14];

    public ushort A { get { return a; } }
    public byte this [int i]
    {
        get 
        {
            byte b1;
            fixed (byte* b2 = b)
            {
                b1 = b2[i];
            }
            return b1;
        }
    }
 };
```

Comment: note: can be simplified to `fixed (byte* ptr = b) { return ptr[i]; }` - but essentially, yup: this

Comment: +1 OK, but what I would like to index is not X itself, but its field b. Suppose that I have another array field, c. I would like to index both b, like x.B[i], and c, like x.C[i], where x is of type X.

Comment: @Chris I extended the question to include the case when there are multiple array fields. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the suggestion, I simplified the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, which is based on the idea of [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 14)]
public struct YB
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] private fixed byte b[14];
  public byte this[int i] { get { fixed (byte* p = b) { return p[i]; } } }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct YC
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] private fixed byte c[8];
  public byte this[int i] { get { fixed (byte* p = c) { return p[i]; } } }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 24)]
public unsafe struct Y
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] private ushort a;
  [FieldOffset(2)] private YB b;
  [FieldOffset(16)] private YC c;

  public ushort A { get { return a; } }
  public YB B { get { return b; } }
  public YC C { get { return c; } }
};
```